# Make a Python program print out data from a file while excluding stuff from other file

Tags: python

Sorry for my bad explanation, but Im trying to be as precise as I can.

So lets say that I have 2 files. First file has vehicle details (vehicles.txt) (reg number, make, transmission) etc. The other file (rented.txt) has only registration numbers and rental dates in it. Goal is to print out all the available cars for rental, (all vehicles - the ones which are already rented).

How can I print all the available cars? (Print all the lines, excluding those which have a registration number already in use)

```
vehicles.txt

ABC-123, Example, Manual
DEF-456, Example2, Manual
GHI-789, Example3, Automatic
```

```
rented.txt

DEF-456, 1/1/1999, 5/1/1999
```

I've already tried making a temporary text file where the program writes details from all the cars and deletes rows which have a registration number in use, but that does not seem to work.

What is the way to figure this out?

Comment: Build a dictionary from the data in vehicles.txt (keyed by registration number). Remove keys from that dictionary based on the registration numbers read from rented.txt. What's left in your dictionary will be your available vehicles

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi if your question has been answered please accept the answer and if not please state where you do not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future use please provide some code so we can better understand what you have already tried. I dont know what your code looks like but in terms of the program structure I would read them both into lists. Then loop through all of the vechicles and check that currentVehicle not in RentedVehicleList and if that is true then Print that car as available.